# Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined when using chrome.action or chrome.browserAction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that will redirect me to a URL when clicking on the browser action icon.

I'm trying to use:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
```

but I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined

This is my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "first extension",
    "version": "2.2.12",
    "description": "redirct to a link icon",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icontest.png",
        "default_title": "Do action"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*.twitter.com/*", "https://*.twitter.com/*"],
        "js": ["twterland.js"]
    }],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icontest.png",
        "48": "icontest.png",
        "128": "icontest.png"
    }
}
```

This is my js file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { alert("hi"); });
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems like the code is in your `twterland.js` file, which is your content script. `browserAction` can only be used in extension pages, so you can not use it in content scripts.

Document: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

> However, content scripts have some limitations. **They cannot**:
>    - **Use chrome.* APIs** (except for parts of chrome.extension)
>    - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
>    - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

Put it on the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) instead.

Comment: The link to “background page” is dead.

Answer (score 180):

### ManifestV3

**manifest.json**: add `action` (not `browser_action`), see also the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

```json
  "action": {},
  "background": {"service_worker": "background.js"},
```

**background.js**: use `chrome.action` not `chrome.browserAction`.

#### Classic ManifestV2

For those who already have added something like

```json
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

and still gets `Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined` - just add

```json
"browser_action": {}
```

into your manifest.json

Comment: This is actually my problem. My script was already background. It's just I have never declared any `browser_action` to begin with.

Comment: `"browser_action": {}` is sufficient

Comment: Why????????? This makes no sense... I changed the icon to another file and it failed to execute. I change it back to icon.png and all is well! Thank you, but I am really scratching my head...

Comment: Same for page_action

Comment: this would not work if the manifest version is 3

Comment: Strange that `browserAction` is not marked as deprecatef yet...

Comment: Once you've done this, you also need to click "Clear all" in the Errors page to clear the previous error.

Answer (score 19):

If you do not have a `"browser_action"` property defined in your `manifest.json` then this error may occur. @Kirill's answer works but you also have to add a blank `icon.png` file else chrome will throw an error that it cannot find such a file.

Adding this to the `manifest.json` file *should* suppress this is error:

```
"browser_action": {}
```

Be sure to read the [documentation for further reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)  on how to use the `"browser_action"` setting.

Comment: I have browser_action defined in my manifest, still `chrome.pageAction` is not defined in my background script

Comment: @AlexanderMills The orginal question was regarding `chrome.browserAction` so I'm not sure about `pageAction`.

Comment: I also had to remove and reinstall the extension.

Answer (score 10):

The same problem may appear if you are using manifest_version 3.
In this case

- "background.scripts" should be replaced with "background.service_worker"
- "browser_action" should be replaced with "action"
- in js code chrome.browserAction should be replaced with chrome.action

detailed information could be found here: [Manifest version 3 migration documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/)

Comment: Thank you! This saved me - i knew about the first three but the `chrome.action` one is the one i didn't know about!

Comment: Renaming browserAction to action was the missing puzzle piece, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting this, adding

```
"persistent": true
```

to my background declaration in manifest.json solved it.

Comment: While this "solves" the situation, there are apparently quite a few reasons *not* to have `"persistent": true`, so it isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: Note that if your Chrome extension is using Version3 in the Manifest, this feature won't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that you can heave only one of `app`, `browser_action`, `page_actions` present in your manifest‎.json file.

For example, to use the [chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) you should have the `browser_action` field in your manifest‎.json.

Answer (score 0):

Since manifest v3, browser_action is changed to action. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/api-calls#replace-browser-page-actions

So in the manifest, have the following:

```
"action": {},
```

And then you can handle the extension click with:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {...})
```

Answer (score -3):

Make sure we don't have jquery.js before background.js in the scripts array of background in manifest.json.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js","jquery.js"]
}
```