# Chrome extension - How can I capture click events on the document vanillaJS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create my first chrome extension and what I would like to do is have a function run each time the user clicks.

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyName",
  "description": "MyDescription",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "contentscript.js" ],
      "all_frames":  true
    }
  ]
}
```

I've then created a js file called "contentscript.js" which contains the following:

```
document.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    alert("test");
}
```

I couldn't find much online apart from this post: [Chrome extension that captures middle click and replaces URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269296/chrome-extension-that-captures-middle-click-and-replaces-url), however that seems to be using jQuery which I would like to avoid if possible (I tried to modify my project based on the above question to work without jQuery but nothing happens once I load my project to chrome in dev mode and click on the page).

I would be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

This is my popup.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
        <!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <title>wow!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-content">
            <h1 class="main-title">w0w!</h1>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't report middle/wheel click in `click` event. Use `"mousedown"` or `"auxclick"`.

Comment: You should add icon.png (extension icon for browser action) in same folder, otherwise chrome won't load it. Do you see your extension on extensions bar (top right corner)? I have tested and after adding icon your extension works as expected.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm trying to capture left click, not middle mouse click.

Comment: @Gaiozz I already have icons setup, and the extensions loads succesfully (I can see my popup.html when I click the icon in the top right), its just that nothing happens when I click.

Comment: For a left click the code is correct and it works for me. Make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page, also reload the web page because manifest-declared content scripts run only when the page is fully [re]loaded. If this doesn't help, try **window**.addEventListener('mousedown', clickHandler, **true**) and use `"run_at": "document_start"` in content script declaration.

Comment: @wOxxOm Neither of those seem to work for me. I've added my popup.html file to the question in case that makes any difference?

Comment: The popup is a separate page which is not related to the web page or its content script. Apparently there's something else you're not telling us or doing wrong or there's a bug in your browser.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hmm, only other things I've not mentioned is that there is a popup.js file (referenced in popup.html) that is empty, and I'm adding the extension to Chrome in unpacked mode.

Comment: Like I said, the code is correct. Maybe I could guess more if I saw what exactly you're doing in a screencast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't had time to play with this for a while, but had another look today and found the solution. I was using Visual Studio to write my code, and this created a solution folder withing the folder my code was saved in. So seems that Google extensions don't like having any extra bits in there which caused no code to be run.