# Why is chrome.browserAction.onClicked undefined (in the background script)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have exactly the same problem as in the [Why is chrome.browserAction.onClicked undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494232/why-is-chrome-browseraction-onclicked-undefined) but I have only background script and yet I receive the same error:

## Manifest

```
{
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
     "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

## background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab) {
    console.log(tab);
});
```

## Error

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined]

Comment: Add `"browser_action": {}` to manifest.json.

Comment: Haven't noticed that - thank you. @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm This doesn't work for manifest V3. I get the error `'browser_action' requires manifest version of 2 or lower.`

Comment: @ValentinVignal, see the [official migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/): in MV3 it's just `action`.